# Square bracket overloading operator to set instead of get c++

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

For getting the value(i.e the function returns the value)

for ex -

if we do this in main.cpp

```
cout << Object[0] << endl;
```

it will print the first element of the object array.

and the function will look like this

```
double myArray::operator[](int index) const {

    *//your code*
}
```

but what if we need to set the value what would be the prototype going to look like?

Let's say in main.cpp, we have

```
object[0] = 5;
```

Now this should set the first element as 5 we know that it shouldn't return anything!! so return_type is void!! but how we going to pass the index(i.e 0) and the RHS(Right hand side) value into the function?

Comment: Don't tag spam.

Comment: @shmosel Sorry, I didn't understand

Comment: Why did you tag this with `java`?

Comment: @shmosel my bad sorry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just declare two operators

```
const double & myArray::operator[](int index) const {

    *//your code*
}
```

and

```
double & myArray::operator[](int index)  {

    *//your code*
}
```

Comment: i like your answer better.  i'm deleting mine.

Comment: I tried what you did but it's saying the function cannot be overloaded!!

Comment: @helperaskhelp In general case you need to declare the both. For example an object of the class can be passed to a function by constant reference. In this case you need the first operator. If you want to change the object you need the second operator.

Comment: I already have this function to get the value  double operator[](int index) const; I think is it the reason it can't be overload?

Comment: @helperaskhelp It can be overloaded but sometimes instead of a copy of an object of the type double there is required the object itself as for example as in reference_wrapper.  In this case it is better to return constant reference instead of a copy.

Comment: Are you returning the address?

Comment: @helperaskhelp Your operator returns a temporary object of the type double that is a copy of the original object. In my operator declaration there is returned a constant reference to the original object.